# What is the difference between ΔH = ΔU +Δ(PV) and ΔU = q + w?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Here, ΔH = Enthalpy change, ΔU = Change in internal energy, P = pressure and V = volume.

I know that ΔH(Enthalpy) is heat given/taken to/from system at constant pressure. But I have been practicing questions recently on this topic and came to this confusion.

Let me first put out the question I solved:

"One mole of an ideal gas (Cv = 3/2*R) is heated at constant pressure reversibly at 1 atmosphere from 25°C to 100°C. Calculate ΔU and ΔH, Take R =2 cal/K.mol ".

I proceeded to solve the question,
Since

ΔH = nCpΔT = 1 * 5/2 * R * 75 = 375 cal.(Correct answer) and

ΔU = nCvΔT = 1 * 3/2 * R * 75 = 225 cal.(Correct answer)

Now I found out the work done in the process = -PΔV = -nR(T2 - T1) = -150 cal.

Calculation for work done is as follows:

W = -Pext(V2-V1) = -P[(nRT2/P)-(nRT1/P)] = -nR(T2-T1) = -1*2*(373-298) = -150 cal.

But if I try to find out the ΔU using the equation  ΔH = ΔU +Δ(PV),
ΔU = 375 - (-150) = 525 cal.(Wrong)

But if I use first law of thermodynamics, ΔU = q + w,
ΔU = 375 + (-150) = 225 cal, which is the correct answer.

So, my question is why should I use first law of thermodynamics here even though the process is taking place at constant pressure??

Comment: PDelta V=+150, not -150

Comment: You have made a mistake in sign of work as $P\Delta V=150$. Also, first law of thermodynamics is valid everywhere, not just at constant pressure.

Comment: @LightYagami, Can you please refer the post again, I have added the calculation for work done, to my knowledge I have learnt the formula for work done as -PextΔV. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Srini First you have written $-P\Delta V=-150$ which is fine. But when you did the calculation for $\Delta U$, you are subtracting -150, where 150 had to be subtracted.

Comment: @LightYagami, Oh got it thank you so much!!

Comment: You can find useful  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).  

See also [upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The first law of thermodynamics refers to all thermodynamic processes performed on closed systems.  It tells us that for all possible process paths between two thermodynamic equilibrium states, although the heat and work done on the system may vary with respect to these process paths, their sum is always the same, and equal to a thermodynamic state function called the internal energy.  The relation $\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)$ defines a secondary thermodynamic function known as enthalpy, which is a physical property of the system, also independent of process path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trouble comes from the two opposed concepts used in the world to define the work  $\pu{p\Delta V}$.

For theoretical scientists, the work is positive when work is done on the system, when the gas is compressed by an external force. And in such a compression, the volume decreases, so $\pu{\Delta V}$ is negative. So in order for the work to be positive, the work must be : $\pu{w = - p\Delta V}$. So that the total change of internal energy is $\pu{\Delta U = q + w}$.

For practical scientists, and specially for engineers, the work is considered positive when the gaz expands, because the gaseous system is working like a machine that must produce work when heat is given to it. In this case, the work is : $\pu{w = + p\Delta V}$. As a consequence, the internal energy is what remains in the system when heat has been given to it and some work has been produced. So here : $\pu{\Delta U = q - w}$.

Finally both concepts leads to the same final result : $\pu{\Delta U = q - p\Delta V}$

Comment: Thank you so much, got a clearer vision about this .